# Mapping An Array To Logical Array In Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Let's say an `array a=[1,3,8,10,11,15,24]`, and a `logical array b=[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]`, how to get `[1,1,3,1,3,8,1,3,8,1,2,3,8,10]`, see where logic becomes 1 in `b`, the array index of `a` resets so it starts from the beginning, also the same where the logic becomes 0 `a array` starts from beginning and continues as `1,3,8,10..etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `diff` to find where `b` changes, then use `arrayfun` to generate indexes for `a`:

```
a=[1,3,8,10,11,15,24];
b=[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];
idxs = find(diff(b) ~= 0) + 1; % where b changes
startidxs = [1 idxs];
endidxs = [idxs - 1,length(b)];
% indexes for a
ia = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) 1:(y-x+1),startidxs,endidxs,'UniformOutput',0));
res = a(ia);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop and track the state (`0` or `1`) of the `b` array:

```
a = [1,3,8,10,11,15,24];
b = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1];

final = []
index = 0;
state = b(1);
for i = 1:numel(b)
    if b(i) ~= state
        state = b(i);
        index = 1;
    else
        index = index+1;
    end
        final = [final, a(index) ];
end
```